# Image analysis for extracting lines between cells

Tags: image-processing, cells

I have a `2D` image as shown here and need to extract the spatial information about the curves in between each cell division. I have been able to analyze the image and output $\;(x,y)\;$ coordinates where the brightest values `(1.0)` are located in the grid of pixels.

How might I be able to process the image to remove noise (inside the cells) leaving only the lines describing the cell outlines?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of nonlinear filters that are possible. One that might help is the `RidgeFilter`

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyUPZ.jpg"];
ImageAdjust[RidgeFilter[img, 5]]
```

[image]

Let's now clean it up a bit:

```
Pruning[Thinning[SelectComponents[Binarize[ImageAdjust[RidgeFilter[img, 5]], 0.094], 
        "Count", # > 800 &]]]
```

[image]

The above binarizes the output of the ridge filter. This leaves the desired edges plus some junk in the middle. `SelectComponents` then removes all the small components, leaving just the desired edges. The result contains the edges but they have become fat; the `Thinning` function trims them down. The final pruning (as suggested by halirutan) removes a couple of dangling edges.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. This is exactly the push I needed!

Answer (score 7):

Common functions you should look at are [`EdgeDetect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeDetect.html), [`Thinning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thinning.html) and [`Pruning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pruning.html). With the already mentioned `RidgeFilter` this gives

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyUPZ.jpg"];
border = Pruning[Thinning@Closing[EdgeDetect[
  ImageAdjust@RidgeFilter[img, 7], 1], 5], 500];
ColorCombine[{img, img, border}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about doing an initial `TotalVariationFilter`ing with  `Method->"Poisson"`?